# Transaction is optional in Hibernate . But why do we need to use it every time? Is there any alternative?

Tags: java, hibernate

I found that using transaction is optional as hibernate application manages transaction in their own application code.But when i try to execute the code without Transaction,the code executes without any error but there is no data in the database. How can i commit my data without using Transaction(since it is optional)? What is the alternative of Transaction?

```
 Configuration c = new Configuration();
 c.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
 SessionFactory sf = c.buildSessionFactory();

 Session s = sf.openSession();

 //Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
 //some code
 //t.commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [`docs`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Transaction.html)

`public interface Transaction`

Allows the application to define units of work, while maintaining abstraction from the underlying transaction implementation (eg. JTA, JDBC).

A transaction is associated with a Session and is usually instantiated by a call to `Session.beginTransaction()`. A single session might span multiple transactions since the notion of a session (a conversation between the application and the datastore) is of coarser granularity than the notion of a transaction. **However, it is intended that there be at most one uncommitted Transaction associated with a particular Session at any time.**

and therefore it is clear that you cannot do any transaction without `Transaction`

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

> Database, or system, transaction boundaries are always necessary. No communication with the database can occur outside of a database transaction (this seems to confuse many developers who are used to the auto-commit mode). Always use clear transaction boundaries, even for read-only operations (c) [Hibernate transaction demarcation doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-demarcation)

There are docs saying that Transaction is optional.

> (Optional) A single-threaded, short-lived object used by the application to specify atomic units of work. It abstracts the application from the underlying JDBC, JTA or CORBA transaction. A org.hibernate.Session might span several org.hibernate.Transactions in some cases. However, transaction demarcation, either using the underlying API or org.hibernate.Transaction, is never optional. [Basic API's / architecture doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch02.html)

What that actually means is that **if you run your code in an environment (container / framework) which does transaction demarcation for you - you can skip using Hibernate API's for this**.

Alternatives to this API's are [Spring Declarative Transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained) (basically annotations, they have XML way too), [Transaction demarcation in an EJB container](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/jta/trxejb.html), etc - those depend on where you run your code.

Transaction is basic work unit of a database and they are needed for working the DB's, somebody working with a DB should always specify where a transaction starts / ends.

You can read more on [ACID guarantees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) for some context.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @SachinSingh welcome to stackoverflow and please read [What should I do when somebody answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: thanks sir i was trying to do so but it wasn't allowing me to do so as my reputation was less.

Comment: @SachinSingh hm, accepting answers should work regardless. Enjoy your experience here :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work